# How to create a trigger that would save the deleted data (multiple records) to a Production Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I  use a temporary table to keep a good performance of sql-server, I have a copy of that table (production table), I created a trigger that when I delete the data from the temporary table it inserts the data to the production table. The issue it that when I delete the data records from the temporary table it only inserts the first record.

Can I save selected records, from the deleted data records? For example I want to save to Production Table those records that in the field POST = 'T'

Answer (score 0):

This should be a pretty simple requirement along the following lines

```
CREATE TRIGGER YourTrigger
ON Staging
AFTER DELETE 
AS
INSERT INTO Production
SELECT * 
FROM DELETED
```

But using the `OUTPUT` clause may well be more efficient than a trigger anyway

```
DELETE Staging 
OUTPUT DELETED.* 
INTO Production
```

Comment: Can I save selected records, from the deleted data records? For example I want to save to Production Table those records that in the field POST = 'T'.

Comment: @user734781 - Not using the output clause but you can with the trigger. Just add a `WHERE` clause to the `SELECT` from `DELETED`